# Geometric series: calculate quotient and number of elements from sum and first & last element

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, math

Creating evenly spaced numbers on a log scale (a geometric progression) can easily be done for a given base and number of elements if the starting and final values of the sequence are known, e.g., with `numpy.logspace` and `numpy.geomspace`. Now assume I want to define the geometric progression the other way around, i.e., based on the properties of the resulting geometric series. If I know the sum of the series as well as the first and last element of the progression, can I compute the quotient and number of elements?

For instance, assume the first and last elements of the progression are [image: a0] and [image: an] and the sum of the series should be equal to [image: sn]. I know from trial and error that it works out for `n=9` and `r≈1.404`, but how could these values be computed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question but a math question. it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the following two equations for `r` and `n`:

```
a:= An / Ao = r^(n - 1)
```

and

```
s:= Sn / Ao = (r^n - 1) / (r - 1)
```

You can eliminate `n` by

```
s = (r a - 1) / (r - 1)
```

and solve for `r`. Then `n` follows by `log(a) / log(r) + 1`.

---

In your case, from `s = 50` and `a = 15`, we obtain `r = 7/5 = 1.4` and `n = 9.048...`

It makes sense to round `n` to `9`, but then `r^8 = 15` (`r ~ 1.40285`) and `r = 1.4` are not quite compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You have enough information to solve it:

```
Sum of series = a + a*r + a*(r^2) ... + a*(r^(n-1))
= a*((r^n)-1)/(r-1)
= a*((last element * r) - 1)/(r-1)
```

Given the sum of series, `a`, and the last element, you can use the above equation to find the value of `r`.
Plugging in values for the given example:

```
50 = 1 * ((15*r)-1) / (r-1)
50r - 50 = 15r - 1
35r = 49
r = 1.4
```

Then, using `sum of series = a*((r^n)-1)/(r-1)`:

```
50 = 1*((1.4^n)-1)(1.4-1)
21 = 1.4^n
n = log(21)/log(1.4) = 9.04
```

You can approximate `n` and recalculate `r` if `n` isn't an integer.

Comment: r = 1.4 keeps the first equation exact. So why recomputing it ?

Answer (score 2):

We have to reconstruct geometric progesssion, i.e. obtain `a, q, m` (here `^` means *raise into power*):

```
a, a * q, a * q^2, ..., a * q^(m - 1)
```

if we know `first, last, total`:

```
first = a                       # first item
last  = a * q^(m - 1)           # last item
total = a * (q^m - 1) / (q - 1) # sum
```

Solving these equation we can find

```
a = first
q = (total - first) / (total - last)
m = log(last / a) / log(q)
```

if you want to get *number* of items `n`, note that `n == m + 1`

Code:

```
import math

...

def Solve(first, last, total):
    a = first
    q = (total - first) / (total - last)
    n = math.log(last / a) / math.log(q) + 1
    
    return (a, q, n);
```

[Fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/LdlN965pnM5)

If you put your data (`1`, `15`, `50`) you'll get the solution

```
a = 1 
q = 1.4 
n = 9.04836151801382 # not integer
```

since `n` is not an integer you, probably want to adjust; let `last == 15` be exact, when `total` can vary. In this case `q = (last / first) ^ (1 / (n - 1))` and `total = first * (q ^ n - 1) / (q - 1)`

```
a = 1
q = 1.402850552006674
n = 9

total = 49.752 # now n is integer, but total <> 50
```